# Push same notification to multiple Android devices using Parse in PHP

Tags: php, android, parse-platform

I want to send a notification to multiple **Android** devices using **Parse** in **PHP**. For this, I have followed the method given on this [link](https://parse.com/questions/php-rest-example-of-targeted-push), but this provides solution for only one device. So, I created a loop with that method in it and iterated through the `array` containing `objectIDs`. However, it also didn't work. I also looked around this website, but couldn't find desired solution. Please help.

Here is the code.

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($devicesArray);$i++)
    {
        $target_device = $devicesArray[$i];  // using object Id of target Installation.
        $push_payload = json_encode(array(
                "where" => array(
                        "objectId" => $target_device,
                ),
                "data" => array(
                        "alert" => "New message received in ".$groupName." ."
                )
            ));

            $rest = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_PORT,443);
            curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);
            curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$push_payload);
            curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                    array("X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
                            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey,
                            "Content-Type: application/json"));

            $response = curl_exec($rest);
    }
```

`$devicesArray` contains object IDs and that code inside `for` loop is given on the link mentioned above. The issue is the notification is delivered to only one device, but I want it to be delivered to all devices. Here is the snapshot of Parse dashboard.

[image]

Here "1" and "0" are the no. of push sent.

Comment: please post your code, and point us to the issue

Comment: @swidmann I have added my code. Please check it now.

Comment: do you have device tokens for your devices?

Comment: @swidmann, Yes, I have device tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try something like this below. I have no big experience with parse.com so maybe `$in` is only `in`or you don't need it at all, maybe you can try it:

```
$push_payload = json_encode(array(
    "where" => array(
            "deviceToken" => array( '$in' => array( "deviceToken_1", "deviceToken_2", "deviceToken_3" ) )
    ),
    "data" => array(
            "alert" => "New message received in ".$groupName." ."
    )
));
```

instead of `array( '$in' => array( "deviceToken_1", "deviceToken_2", "deviceToken_3" ) )`

**you could try this:**

```
array( 'in' => array( "deviceToken_1", "deviceToken_2", "deviceToken_3" ) )
```

**or that:**

```
array( array( "deviceToken_1", "deviceToken_2", "deviceToken_3" ) )
```

**or just:**

```
array(  "deviceToken_1", "deviceToken_2", "deviceToken_3" )
```

Comment: Thanks. However, device token is not stored in database, but object id is. That is why I need a solution that allows me to send notification using only object IDs.

Comment: I'm sorry I just answered it, because of your comment: "Yes, I have device tokens". Maybe you can work with channels?